# TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object - Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-migrations, python-datetime

I've deployed my Django application to DigitalOcean server via nginx, gunicorn. Today I wanted to add the script `models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)` for saving the date when message from user was sent, but during migration (after pulling the entire repository from github on ubuntu server) I'm getting following error. And I guess the problem is in migration files, but don't know how can I manipulate them on server and how to do it safely, without losing any data.

Error:

```
Applying pragmatechapp.0004_auto_20200328_1036...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/kerimov/pragmatechproject/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/kerimov/pragmatechproject/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/kerimov/pragmatechproject/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/kerimov/pragmatechproject/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/kerimov/pragmatechproject/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/kerimov/pragmatechproject/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 234, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "/home/kerimov/pragmatechproject/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/kerimov/pragmatechproject/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/kerimov/pragmatechproject/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 245, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/home/kerimov/pragmatechproject/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 124, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/home/kerimov/pragmatechproject/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 112, in database_forwards
    field,
  File "/home/kerimov/pragmatechproject/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 433, in add_field
    definition, params = self.column_sql(model, field, include_default=True)
  File "/home/kerimov/pragmatechproject/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 161, in column_sql
    default_value = self.effective_default(field)
  File "/home/kerimov/pragmatechproject/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 233, in effective_default
    return field.get_db_prep_save(self._effective_default(field), self.connection)
  File "/home/kerimov/pragmatechproject/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 793, in get_db_prep_save
    return self.get_db_prep_value(value, connection=connection, prepared=False)
  File "/home/kerimov/pragmatechproject/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1435, in get_db_prep_value
    value = self.get_prep_value(value)
  File "/home/kerimov/pragmatechproject/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1414, in get_prep_value
    value = super().get_prep_value(value)
  File "/home/kerimov/pragmatechproject/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1274, in get_prep_value
    return self.to_python(value)
  File "/home/kerimov/pragmatechproject/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1375, in to_python
    parsed = parse_datetime(value)
  File "/home/kerimov/pragmatechproject/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/dateparse.py", line 106, in parse_datetime
    match = datetime_re.match(value)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Note: I should solve this problem very quickly, please, everyone, who knows the answer, help me. I'm really depressed and stressed.

Comment: You need to share your migrations files. atleast `pragmatechapp.0004_auto_20200328_1036` and the 0003 ones

Comment: @ruddra, but how ? They are on a server, how can I reach them ?

Comment: Did you add this field to the existing modal?

Comment: @MKPatel, yes, buddy, for sure

Comment: I think you have to add `default=None` in that field for existing data in that modal.

Answer (score -1):

As a solution I've used deleting the migrations one by one with a command `find . -path "*/migrations/{my_migration_names}.py" -not -name "__init__.py" -delete`. To get name of all of my migration files you should run `python3 manage.py showmigrations` command.